# Picking only the real solutions from the output of NRoots

Tags: polynomials

I'm using `NRoots` to quickly extract the roots for cubic polynomials, as my testing showed this was faster then either `FindRoot` or `NSolve` for this particularly simple case. However, I only need the real solutions. But according to the documentation, `NRoots` does not take `Reals` as an option. Is there a simple way to pick the real solutions out?

Comment: FYI: A concrete example in *Mathematica* code almost always speeds the appearance of good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like that

```
Cases[x /. {ToRules@NRoots[x^3 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]}, _Real]
```

Comment: Or if you wish the result to be rules: `Cases[{ToRules@
   NRoots[x^3 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]},  _?(Element[x /. #, Reals] &)]` or `Select[{ToRules@NRoots[x^3 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]}, 
 Element[x /. #, Reals] &]`